# VS2010 slow publishing web applications

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, deployment, msbuild

Whenever I publish a web application (both web forms and MVC), it takes a long time, even for a simple application containing around 10 files.

The build process takes less than a second, but the publish process easily takes more than a minute. I'm publishing to a local folder.

Why is publish taking so much longer than build? Is there anything I can do to speed up the process?

Comment: I have found that VS has slowed down dramatically with the Publish process and seems to be extremely slow when simply copying files (such as .js files), not necessarily when compiling. If anyone has another solution I would appreciate it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The publish will be compiling and then running through the aspnet_compiler, which may take a little while to generate custom DLLs for all the code even if it's a small site.

There are a some nice titbits on this blog for optimising it: [ASPNet Compiler compilation speed](http://programminglife.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/aspnet_compiler-compilation-speed-part-1/)

Hope that helps and good luck :)

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks. I wasn't able to gain much performance from the tips in the link, but always nice to have an explanation.